# eSata to USB 3.0 connected drive doesn't show up as a selectable drive

Tags: usb, usb-3, esata

I have an external hard drive that has an eSata port. The computer I am connecting it to has a motherboard that doesn't not support eSata to eSata, so, I'm using an eSata to USB 3.0 converter to connect.

When I connect everything, the device shows up under "Storage Controllers" inside Device Manager as "USB Attached SCSI (UAS) Mass Storage Device". However, I'm unable to select the drive and view it's contents. I've plugged the drive into another computer and it works perfectly fine. Basically, the drive doesn't show up inside Windows File Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the drive is not being mounted to a drive letter. You may have to do it manually (the first time, at least).

1. Open the Control Panel and search for Administrative Tools
2. Under Administrative Tools, access Computer Management
3. Under Computer Management, look for Disk Management in the left pane (Alternatively, you can search for diskmgr.msc from the Windows 10 Start menu)
4. With the converter and drive plugged in, look for the new drive in the list of disks.
5. Right-click on the desired partition on the external drive and select "Change Drive Letter and Paths..."
6. Click the "Add" button in the dialog and then select the desired drive letter you wish this drive to be mounted on.
7. Click "Ok" on both dialogs. Your external drive should now be mounted under the selected drive letter. It should then mount under that drive letter when it is attached in the future (unless you change it later).